# Possible to transfer Google Play Balance from one Google account to another?

Tags: google-play-store, google

Actually I am using 2 Google accounts in my device and first is my permanent while second is only for special purposes.
I have mistakenly added my funds to second account instead of first one and now finding if there is anyway to transfer those bucks to my primary account so that i can make purchases. It is not convenient for me to make purchase from my secondary account.

Note - I have read that there is a way but that is as Google Gift Cards but that I can't purchase from Google play balance.